# Dates between date1 and date2 are not working in cross joining

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I am trying to filter data with dates between but it insert null `0 rows created` its cross joining table I am not aware is there problem due to cross joining or something else. There is no error message
without dates it works fine any solution Please

```
insert into PAY_IN_OUT2 (EMP_CODE, DATE_IN, DATE_OUT, ATT_DATE, DATE_INA, DATE_OUTA, DATE_INB, DATE_OUTB, DATE_INC, DATE_OUTC, ATT_PRESENT)
select a.EMPLOYEE_ID1, b.DT, b.DT1, B.ATT_DT, B.DT3, B.DT4, B.DT4, B.DT5, B.DT5, B.DT3, 'P'
from CALENDAR_DATES4 b cross join  EMPLOYEES a
WHERE A.EMPLOYEE_ID1 BETWEEN 70001 AND 70009 
AND B.ATT_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/02/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('20/02/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') ;
```

without this its working fine but I have to filter this with dates `AND   B.ATT_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('10/02/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('20/02/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')`

Comment: What is the data type of `att_dt`?  Is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: If it works without joining to `employees`  maybe that's your problem.  Run 
select * from employees where EMPLOYEE_ID1 BETWEEN 70001 AND 70009; 
see if anything comes up

Comment: @GordonLinoff `att_dt` data type is Date

Comment: Try this: `B.ATT_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021/02/10', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE('2021/02/20', 'yyyy/mm/dd')`

Comment: @d0little I tried this but not worked and shown this never effect because its changes nothing dear

Comment: @EoinS I removed cross join removed employees table and id but only table calendar4 but no effect

Comment: What do you get if you do `SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID1 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID1 BETWEEN 70001 AND 70009`? And what do you get if you do `SELECT * FROM CALENDAR_DATES4 WHERE ATT_DT BETWEEN DATE '2021-02-10' AND DATE '2021-02-20';`? If one of them returns zero rows then the `CROSS JOIN` of the two will return zero rows.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks dear, doing some work on these dates I think I deleted data from the table, first I see your answer and think that what is it, it just bring data, then think that  try to check is there any data or not, now checked there is no data and entered data from backup and my own query is working. Thanks to pointing me

Answer (score 0):

If you're cross joining two tables and filtering on each table, and you end up selecting 0 rows, then at least one of your predicates is causing no rows to be returned.

For example, here's a set of queries demonstrating some different results, depending on what the predicates cause to be returned:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 ID, 10 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 20 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID, 30 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 ID, 40 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 ID, 50 val FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 'A' col1, 'AA' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'B' col1, 'BA' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'C' col1, 'AC' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'D' col1, 'DD' col2 FROM dual)
SELECT 1 case_no, -- case 1: no rows expected to be returned (no t1 rows with an id between 6 and 10)
       t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM   t1
       CROSS JOIN t2
WHERE  t1.id BETWEEN 6 AND 10
AND    t2.col2 LIKE 'A%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 case_no, -- case 2: no rows expected to be returned (no t2 rows with a col2 starting with "C")
       t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM   t1
       CROSS JOIN t2
WHERE  t1.id BETWEEN 2 AND 4
AND    t2.col2 LIKE 'C%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 case_no, -- case 3: no rows expected to be returned (no t1 rows with an id between 6 and 10, and no t2 rows with a col2 starting with "C")
       t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM   t1
       CROSS JOIN t2
WHERE  t1.id BETWEEN 6 AND 10
AND    t2.col2 LIKE 'C%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 case_no, -- case 4: 6 rows expected to be returned (3 t1 rows with an id between 2 and 4, and 2 t2 rows with a col2 starting with "A"; 3 x 2 = 6)
       t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM   t1
       CROSS JOIN t2
WHERE  t1.id BETWEEN 2 AND 4
AND    t2.col2 LIKE 'A%';

   CASE_NO         ID        VAL COL1 COL2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---- ----
         4          2         20 A    AA
         4          3         30 A    AA
         4          4         40 A    AA
         4          2         20 C    AC
         4          3         30 C    AC
         4          4         40 C    AC
```

You can see that only case 4 (rows in both tables match the predicates) has any rows returned by the cross join.

---

ETA: if you were wanting to see employee rows regardless of whether there are matching date rows or not, you would need to use an outer join, e.g. using my earlier example, case 2 would become:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 ID, 10 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 20 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID, 30 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 ID, 40 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 ID, 50 val FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 'A' col1, 'AA' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'B' col1, 'BA' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'C' col1, 'AC' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'D' col1, 'DD' col2 FROM dual)
SELECT t1.*,
       t2.*
FROM   t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.col2 LIKE 'C%'
WHERE  t1.id BETWEEN 2 AND 4;

        ID        VAL COL1 COL2
---------- ---------- ---- ----
         2         20      
         3         30      
         4         40
```